# lvcreate snapshot creates a larger snapshot than the snapshot size

Tags: rhel, lvm

I'm running

```
lvcreate --size $snapshot_size --snapshot --name mdb-snap-00 /dev/vg0/mongodb
```

to create a snapshot of our mongo partition.

`$snapshot_size` is 362M

However after creating it, `lsblk` gives me

```
nvme0n1                 259:0    0 442.4G  0 disk 
├─vg0-mongodb-real      252:1    0 221.2G  0 lvm  
│ ├─vg0-mongodb         252:0    0 221.2G  0 lvm  /mnt/data
│ └─vg0-mdb--snap--00   252:3    0 221.2G  0 lvm  
└─vg0-mdb--snap--00-cow 252:2    0   364M  0 lvm  
  └─vg0-mdb--snap--00   252:3    0 221.2G  0 lvm
```

This is an issue for me, because I'm trying to dd the snapshot pipe it to gzip and pipe that to an aws bucket but it timeouts everytime. I just learnt that this happens because it's trying to do the whole 221G disk even though the data on it and the specified snapshot size are only 362Mb

Edit

```
root@ip-10-0-97-77:~# lvs
  LV          VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin  Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  mdb-snap-00 vg0  swi-a-s--- 364.00m      mongodb 0.48                                   
  mongodb     vg0  owi-aos--- 221.15g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical volumes are multiples of the PE (physical extents) size which is by default 4MiB. 362 cannot be divided by 4 thus LVM rounds up the size to 364.

I don't think it is easily possible to change the PE size.

You could create a 362 MiB file, though, put a loop device onto it and configure the snapshot manually (`dmsetup`), having it point there. But that is probably something for experienced users.

You are reading more than the intended 362/364 MiB because you are reading from the wrong device. The snapshot device is a copy of the original one thus it has the same size. You have to read from the COW device directly.

Comment: I did try creating a 364M partition, but the snapshot size still came all the way to 221G, I'm sure I'm missing something, because running dd with pv (pipe viewer) I see the GBs copied go way over 364M

Comment: @Jonathan I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: How do I specify the cow device?
`root@ip-10-0-97-77:~# sudo dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap-00-cow | gzip > backup.gz
dd: failed to open '/dev/vg0/mdb-snap-00-cow': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Jonathan It is `/dev/mapper/...`